# Tool tip in JPanel in JTable not working

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tooltip

I have a `JTable`. One column holds a `JPanel` which contains some `JLabels` with `ImageIcons`. I have created a custom cell render and all works fine apart from the tool tip on the `JLabel`. When I mouse over any of these `JLabels` I need to show the `Tooltip` of that particular `JLabel`. Its not showing the tootlip of the `JLabel`.

Here is the `CustomRenderer`.

```
private class CustomRenderer extends
            DefaultTableCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column) {   

            if (value != null && value instanceof List) {

                JPanel iconsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                List<ImageIcon> iconList = (List<ImageIcon>) value;
                int xPos = 0;
                for (ImageIcon icon : iconList) {
                    JLabel iconLabel = new JLabel(icon);
                    iconLabel.setToolTipText(icon.getDescription());
                    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                    gbc.gridy = 1;
                    gbc.gridx = xPos++;
                    iconsPanel.add(iconLabel, gbc);
                }
                iconsPanel.setBackground(isSelected ? table
                        .getSelectionBackground() : table.getBackground());
                this.setVerticalAlignment(CENTER);
                return iconsPanel;
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post some code of the portion in question.

Comment: [For better help sooner, please include an sscce](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: It is not showing the tooltip because there is no real component there. JTable works with a renderer - all you get is the paintComponent() of the component returned by the table cell renderer

Comment: @ControlAltDel Actually, if you set it on the component returned by the TableCellRenderer, it does work because the JTable will re-prepare the TableCellRenderer for the hovered cell and will retrieve the tooltip that has been set on the TableCellRenderer

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Well I'll be darned it does work!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you set tooltips on subcomponents of the component returned by your CellRenderer. To perform what you want, you should consider override `getToolTipText(MouseEvent e)` on the JTable. From the event, you can find on which row and column the mouse is, using:

```
java.awt.Point p = e.getPoint();
int rowIndex = rowAtPoint(p);
int colIndex = columnAtPoint(p);
```

From there you could then re-prepare the cell renderer, find which component is located at the mouse position and eventually retrieve its tooltip.

Here is a snippet of how you could override JTable getToolTipText:

```
@Override
public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent event) {
    String tip = null;
    Point p = event.getPoint();

    // Locate the renderer under the event location
    int hitColumnIndex = columnAtPoint(p);
    int hitRowIndex = rowAtPoint(p);

    if (hitColumnIndex != -1 && hitRowIndex != -1) {
        TableCellRenderer renderer = getCellRenderer(hitRowIndex, hitColumnIndex);
        Component component = prepareRenderer(renderer, hitRowIndex, hitColumnIndex);
        Rectangle cellRect = getCellRect(hitRowIndex, hitColumnIndex, false);
        component.setBounds(cellRect);
        component.validate();
        component.doLayout();
        p.translate(-cellRect.x, -cellRect.y);
        Component comp = component.getComponentAt(p);
        if (comp instanceof JComponent) {
            return ((JComponent) comp).getToolTipText();
        }
    }

    // No tip from the renderer get our own tip
    if (tip == null) {
        tip = getToolTipText();
    }

    return tip;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I set the tooltip to JPanel in my code its working properly. But the requirement here is to display tooltips for each JLabel inside JPanel (JPanel is added to one particular column in the JTable).

Comment: @user1430989 please whats wrong with example from [Sn'Oracle JTable tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableToolTipsDemoProject/src/components/TableToolTipsDemo.java)

Comment: @user1430989 I posted a version of JTable.getToolTipText that should work on your code.

Comment: Thank you Guillaume Polet. Its working good. Thanks for your time.