# JLabels in JPanel in JTable tool tips not working

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel

I've got a JTable with a custom cell renderer. I'm adding a panel with multiple JLabels in it to the JTable. The problem is i cant seem to get the tool tip of each one when the mouse is hovered over each JLabel. I dont want to set the jpanel tooltip, i want to display the tool tips that i set on the 3 JLabels inside the jpanel.

Heres my JTable initialization:

```
public static JTable users = new JTable(model) {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Object> getColumnClass(int column) {
        return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
    }

    @Override
    public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent event) {
        String tip = null;
        Point p = event.getPoint();

        // Locate the renderer under the event location
        int hitColumnIndex = columnAtPoint(p);
        int hitRowIndex = rowAtPoint(p);

        if (hitColumnIndex != -1 && hitRowIndex != -1) {
            TableCellRenderer renderer = getCellRenderer(hitRowIndex, hitColumnIndex);
            Component component = prepareRenderer(renderer, hitRowIndex, hitColumnIndex);
            Rectangle cellRect = getCellRect(hitRowIndex, hitColumnIndex, false);
            component.setBounds(cellRect);
            component.validate();
            component.doLayout();
            p.translate(-cellRect.x, -cellRect.y);
            Component comp = component.getComponentAt(p);
            if (comp instanceof JComponent) {
                return ((JComponent) comp).getToolTipText();
            }
        }

        // No tip from the renderer get our own tip
        if (tip == null) {
            tip = getToolTipText();
        }

        return tip;
    }
};
```

and my Custom cell render code:

```
public class TransparentRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer  implements TableCellRenderer {

public JPanel p = new JPanel();

    ........

// This method is called each time a cell in a column
// using this renderer needs to be rendered.
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int rowIndex, int vColIndex) {

    ....


    // Now lets color in the table accordingly..
    if (value.toString().equals(gmeLobby.user)) {
        JLabel l = new JLabel(value.toString());
        l.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        p.add(l);

        //setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    } else {
        // If username is not yours
        //setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);

        if(value instanceof ImageIcon)
        {
            final JLabel l = new JLabel();
            l.setIcon((ImageIcon) value);
            l.setAlignmentY(0.85f);
            l.setToolTipText(((ImageIcon) value).getDescription());
            p.add(l);

            if(vColIndex==0)
            {
            final JLabel w = new JLabel();
            final JLabel d = new JLabel();
            try {
                w.setIcon(gmeImages.gmeImages("globe"));
                w.setToolTipText(((ImageIcon) value).getDescription());
                d.setIcon(gmeImages.gmeImages("dnds"));
                d.setToolTipText(((ImageIcon) value).getDescription());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            p.add(d);
            p.add(w);
            setPosition(w, 5, 0);
            setPosition(d, 15, 2);
            }
            setPosition(l, 0, 0);

        }else{
            JLabel l = new JLabel(value.toString());
            l.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            p.add(l);

        }
        return p;
    }

    if (isSelected) {
        setBackground(new Color(rsbc.getRed() - 100, rsbc.getGreen(), rsbc.getBlue()));
    } else {
        setBackground(bgu);
    }

    if (hasFocus) {
        // this cell is the anchor and the table has the focus
        p.setBackground(new Color(rsbc.getRed() - 100, rsbc.getGreen(), rsbc.getBlue()));
    }


    // Since the renderer is a component, return itself

    return this;
}
```

any help would be great. The current override on the JTable for the tooltip only seems to be getting the tooltip of the first component added.

Thanks

EDIT:

Thanks all who were helping, While making the SSCCE as Andrea commented, i seemed to get the problem fixed, not to sure what the error is exacly, i believe it might be something to do with the way i initialized the imageicon variables.

Anyway a sample program with 2 imageicons in a cell with a tooltip on each image is following:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class design extends JFrame{

// Create the JTable users list and set editable to false
public static DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    public static JTable users = new JTable(model) {
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;

        }

        @Override
        public Class<? extends Object> getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }

        @Override
        public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent event) {
            String tip = null;
            Point p = event.getPoint();

            // Locate the renderer under the event location
            int hitColumnIndex = columnAtPoint(p);
            int hitRowIndex = rowAtPoint(p);

            if (hitColumnIndex != -1 && hitRowIndex != -1) {
                TableCellRenderer renderer = getCellRenderer(hitRowIndex, hitColumnIndex);
                Component component = prepareRenderer(renderer, hitRowIndex, hitColumnIndex);
                Rectangle cellRect = getCellRect(hitRowIndex, hitColumnIndex, false);
                component.setBounds(cellRect);
                component.validate();
                component.doLayout();
                p.translate(-cellRect.x, -cellRect.y);
                Component comp = component.getComponentAt(p);
                if (comp instanceof JComponent) {
                    return ((JComponent) comp).getToolTipText();
                }
            }

            // No tip from the renderer get our own tip
            if (tip == null) {
                tip = getToolTipText();
            }

            return tip;
        }
    };

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws Exception 
 */
public design() throws Exception
{
    initialize();

    setSize(400, 400);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(users);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new design();
}

public static void initialize() throws Exception
{

    model.addColumn("icons");
    model.addColumn("text");

    users.setRowHeight(40);

    TableColumn col = users.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    col.setCellRenderer(new TransparentRenderer());
    TableColumn col2 = users.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
    col2.setCellRenderer(new TransparentRenderer());

    model.addRow(new Object[] { new ImageIcon(), "text here" });
}

   }

 class TransparentRenderer extends JPanel  implements TableCellRenderer {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public JPanel p = new JPanel();
private static SpringLayout spring = new SpringLayout();

public TransparentRenderer() throws Exception, BadLocationException {p.setLayout(spring);}

// This method is called each time a cell in a column
// using this renderer needs to be rendered.
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int rowIndex, int vColIndex)       {

        if(value instanceof ImageIcon)
        {            
            if(vColIndex==0)
            {
            JLabel w = new JLabel();
            JLabel d = new JLabel();
            try {
                ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon();
                extracted("http://fxtrade.oanda.com/wandacache/star_icon-c10fffd09c7a7548f329f56e446f3cfe5463558b.png"
                        , icon1, "Tooltip for icon 1");

                ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon();
                extracted("http://hotels.online.com.sg/DB/icon/star_icon2.gif"
                        , icon2, "Tooltip for icon 2");

                w.setIcon(icon1);
                w.setToolTipText("ToolTip 1");
                d.setIcon(icon2);
                d.setToolTipText("ToolTip 2");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            p.add(d);
            p.add(w);
            setPosition(d, 5, 2);
            setPosition(w, 5, 0);
            }

            return p;
        }else{
            add(new JLabel(value.toString()));
        }       
    return this;
}

public void setPosition(JComponent c, int w, int n)
{
    spring.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, c, w, SpringLayout.WEST, p);
    spring.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, c, n, SpringLayout.NORTH, p);
}

public void extracted(String link, ImageIcon icon, String desc) throws Exception
{
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(link));
    icon.setImage(image);

    if(desc.equals("")){} else{ icon.setDescription(desc);}
}
}
```

Thanks to all who helped :)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your code work at all? `TransparentRenderer` is a singleton per column and `getTableCellRendererComponent`is called for each cell row by row. It seems that which each cell to be rendered a new child is added to the variable `p`. That might be the reason why you always see only the first component.

Comment: And you should check if your code works if `value.toString().equals(gmeLobby.user)` is `true`: in this case it returns `this` which has no parent-child-relation to the panel `p`.

Comment: http://oi46.tinypic.com/2m4w2gx.jpg

First of thanks for the fast reply, This is a current picture of the working renderer, I Have also removed the variable p and made the transparentRenderer class extend JPanel instead. However its still not working, in this image you will see the 3 JLabels in the first collumn in which im trying to get the tooltip of. hope this further helps you Michael.

Comment: Please try more than one entry in the table and change selection sometimes. For the tooltip problem: does it work if you set the tootip text on `p` and use `((JComponent) component).getToolTipText()` as fallback?

Comment: Moreover: is `comp instanceof JComponent` sometimes `true`: that is does `p.translate` work as expected?

Comment: No, that will set the current cell tooltip to that single tooltip text. i was refering to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854831/tool-tip-in-jpanel-in-jtable-not-working. 

<br> ok i will try mate thanks

Comment: not workin when adding muliple items such as a array to the cell.